# Figure out mcrypt key when knowing hash and plain

Tags: php, encryption, hash, mcrypt

i have 2 functions:

```
function Encrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey = "") {
if (!$sSecretKey) {
    $sSecretKey = $GLOBALS['key'];
}
return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $sSecretKey, $sValue,          MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), 

MCRYPT_RAND))));
}
```

and

```
function Decrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey = "") {
if (!$sSecretKey) {
    $sSecretKey = $GLOBALS['key'];
}
return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $sSecretKey, base64_decode($sValue), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 

MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)));
}
```

is it possible to get the key which was used when i have a plain key and its hash?

PLAIN: checkingkeyisright

HASH: W0Kdv34iN5Gpkzc4DlisOw4Pynry/O9TLkUq6pwXxY8=

Comment: If it was, it would make the job of codebreakers a whole lot easier

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not. Recovering the key given the ciphertext and plaintext is something which cryptographic ciphers, such as Rijndael, are specifically designed to make infeasible.